# why my batch count is getting change?

Tags: batch, schedulebatch

Today i noted something while monitoring the apex job.

My batch job scope size is 20 .

I have 30,000 user.

so the number of batch should be  30,000/20  = 1500 (batches).  But i saw it keep on changes for each batch run.

Any advise.

Comment: Do you have a control for your batch query? A WHERE clause perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure you have exactly 30000 users? And that you are selecting all of this users without applying a filter?

Comment: I am filtering with isActive and some other criteria ? . So the batch recount count is 30,000